# Read error: ssl=0x707d0912c8: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort

Tags: android, ssl, p2p, mtls

I am making an Android application where I am trying to set up an SSL Socket between two peers. When initiating the client and server I get this error message: Read error: ssl=0x707d0912c8: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort. Does anyone know what the problem can be?

```
2021-03-15 12:38:26.820 14794-19150/com.example.testaware D/LOG-Test-Aware-App-Server: Read error: ssl=0x707d0912c8: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
2021-03-15 12:38:26.821 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x707d0912c8: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
2021-03-15 12:38:26.821 699-20377/? I/netd: interfaceSetCfg() <24.82ms>
2021-03-15 12:38:26.821 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.821 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.read(NativeSsl.java:411)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.821 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:583)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.821 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:248)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.822 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:288)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.822 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:347)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.822 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2454)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.822 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2470)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.822 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2947)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.822 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:858)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.822 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:353)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.822 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.example.testaware.AppServer.lambda$new$0$AppServer(AppServer.java:63)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.822 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at com.example.testaware.-$$Lambda$AppServer$ooJGZGiLsVQGTcSkPsN_XmX4et8.run(Unknown Source:6)
2021-03-15 12:38:26.822 14794-19150/com.example.testaware W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

The code for the client is :

```
 public AppClient(KeyPair keyPair, SSLContext sslContext){
        this.keyPair = keyPair;
        this.sslContext = sslContext;
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        sslSocket = null;
        this.inet6Address = MainActivity.getPeerIpv6();
      
        try {
            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            while(running){
                sslSocket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(inet6Address, Constants.SERVER_PORT);
                inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream()));
                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeUTF("clientHello");
                outputStream.flush();
                //TODO: send client hello message
                while(running){
                    if (inputStream != null){
                        String strMessageFromClient = (String) inputStream.readUTF();
                        ChatActivity.setChat(strMessageFromClient);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(sslSocket != null){
                try {
                    sslSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    public boolean sendMessage(String message){
        if(outputStream == null){
            return false;
        }
        Runnable sendMessageRunnable = () -> {
            try {
                outputStream.writeUTF(message);
                outputStream.flush();

                MessageListItem chatMsg = new MessageListItem(message, ChatActivity.getLocalIp());
                ChatActivity.messageList.add(chatMsg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        sendService.submit(sendMessageRunnable);
        return true;
    }
```

And the server:

```
public AppServer(SSLContext serverSSLContext, int serverPort){
        running = true;
        Runnable serverTask = () -> {  
            running  = true;
            try {
                SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) serverSSLContext.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(serverPort);
                serverSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true);
                while (running) {
                    SSLSocket sslClientSocket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
                    inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sslClientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    while(running){
                        if (inputStream != null){
                            String strMessageFromClient = (String) inputStream.readUTF();
                            MessageListItem chatMsg = new MessageListItem(strMessageFromClient, "ipv6_other_user"); 
                            messageList.add(chatMsg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException  e) {
                Log.d(LOG, Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
        serverThread.start();
    }
```